# subtract two columns in a tab'ed file (python)

Tags: python, tabs

I have been tinkering with some coordinates which I want to check against eachother.

I have a tab'ed filed, which consist of 6 columns. These are the last 4 columns I want to subtract, and get the result in two columns after the last coordinate column. Also tab'ed.

I want to do this for quite large files, is this possible? And if not, how can I do it with rather small files? I have done some reading, and the csv module pops up everywhere.

```
    337905.44   5269907.69  337905.38   5269907.78
    337917.95   5269907.55  337917.93   5269907.62
    337930.46   5269907.34  337930.48   5269907.46
    337942.97   5269907.13  337942.84   5269907.06
```

This is how far I got, when I gave up;

```
    import csv
    with open('coor.txt', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

To sum up, all I want to do is to have the first and third column subtracted, and the second and fourth column subtracted, and get the difference in two columns after the last coordinate column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `delimiter=':'` rather than `delimiter='\t'`? It's a tab-separated file, not colon-separated.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('input') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        columns=line.split()
        columns=map(float,columns)
        print "%s | \t %s \t %s" % (line.strip(), columns[0] - columns[2],
                                    columns[1] - columns[3])
```

Outputs

```
337905.44   5269907.69  337905.38   5269907.78 |     0.0599999999977     -0.089999999851
337917.95   5269907.55  337917.93   5269907.62 |     0.0200000000186     -0.070000000298
337930.46   5269907.34  337930.48   5269907.46 |     -0.0199999999604    -0.120000000112
337942.97   5269907.13  337942.84   5269907.06 |     0.129999999946      0.070000000298
```

Using `csv-module`:

```
import csv

with open('input', 'rb') as fd:
    reader=csv.reader(fd,delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        #your calculations
        print row
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If I hade a file of approx 100 000 lines of numbers, how would this affect the code?

Comment: +1 A slightly more robust approach would be to use the `csv` module, though your approach works fine for one-off tasks.

Comment: Don't forget to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if you're new to SO and upvote if you like the answer :-)

Comment: @Kjell - the code above reads the input one line at a time. Did a test-run on a file with 40k lines and it finished in ~1.4 seconds. Fast enough? And with the `with` construct you don't need to close the filehandle.

Comment: @Chinmay-Kanchi - agree, but the input format was very simple so in this case I'd choose not to use it; but generally speaking you are correct

Comment: This is a tab'ed file though, but I think it will do well anyways! Thanks Fredrik! I will register and upvote you :)